# Unintialized local variable 'e' used

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have this code. It should work perfectly. It's a circle calculator; I'm doing is as an exercise. I want the user to have the option to return the the 'main menu.' I made a yes/no prompt using char* e; but it's uninitialized. How can I initialize

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Circlecalc {
public:
    double const pi = 3.1415962543;
    double diameter;
    double radius;
    double circumference;

};

int _welcome() {
    Circlecalc calc;
    cout << endl;
    int i = 0;
    char* e;
    cin >> i;
    while (i != 5)
    {
        switch (i) {
        case(1) :
            cout << "Enter your radius." << endl;
            cin >> calc.radius;
            cout << endl;
            cout << (calc.radius * 2) * calc.pi << endl;
            cout << "Exit? [Y/N]" << endl;
            cin >> e;
            if (e == "Y") {
                _welcome();
            }

            else if (e == "N") {
            }

            else {
                cerr << "Unsupported function" << endl;
            }

        case(2) :
            cout << "Enter your diameter" << endl;
            cin >> calc.diameter;
            cout << endl;
            cout << (calc.diameter * 2) * calc.pi << endl;
            cout << "Exit? [Y/N]" << endl;
            cin >> e;
            if (e == "Y") {
                _welcome();
            }

            else if (e == "N") {
            }

            else {
                cerr << "Unsupported function" << endl;
            }
            break;

        case(3) :
            cout << "Enter the circumference" << endl;
            cin >> calc.circumference;
            cout << endl;
            cout << (calc.circumference / 2) / calc.pi;
            cout << "Exit? [Y/N]" << endl;
            cin >> e;
            if (e == "Y") {
                _welcome();
            }

            else if (e == "N") {
            }

            else {
                cerr << "Unsupported function" << endl;
            }
            break;

        case(4) :
            cout << "Enter the circumference" << endl;
            cin >> calc.circumference;
            cout << endl;
            cout << calc.circumference / calc.pi;
            cout << "Exit? [Y/N]" << endl;
            cin >> e;
            if (e == "Y") {
                _welcome();
            }

            else if (e == "N") {
            }

            else {
                cerr << "Unsupported function" << endl;
            }
            break;

        case(5) :
            return(0);
            break;

        default:
            cerr << "Unsupported function." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `char* e;` by `std::string e;`

Comment: In which line does the compiler complain?

Comment: and what does it say?

Comment: Please follow the steps in this post on debugging small programs. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
char* e;
```

use:

```
std::string e;
```

The reason you get:

```
Unintialized local variable 'e' used
```

is that `e` is not set when passed to operator>> that is used by cin, to initialize it assign an array to it, ie:

```
char arr[128] = {0};
char* e = arr;
```

`operator>>` for cin stream expect that you have provided some memory buffer where read string is located, `char* e;` is not bound to any such buffer, and that would end in (possibly) crash (Undefined Behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

In this case you do not need to.  If you only want a single letter input from the user just use a `char` like

```
char response;
```

Then you would compare it against a character literal instead of a string literal like

```
if (response == 'N' || response == 'n')
```

If you want to compare against a string like `"no"` or `"No"` then I suggest you use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and not worry about having to allocate memory for the string.